# Is there a way I can evaluate a JavaScript function with default parameters using PyV8?

Tags: javascript, python, pyv8

I am trying to call a function from JavaScript in python. I am using PyV8 and I can successfully call a function and print out the result. However, if the function contains a default parameter then I get a Syntax Error.

This works fine.

```py
import PyV8

ctxt = PyV8.JSContext()
ctxt.enter()
ctxt.eval("function example(a){return a;}")
render = ctxt.eval("example('hello');")
print render
```

However, when I make example contain a default parameter like this:

```py
import PyV8

ctxt = PyV8.JSContext()
ctxt.enter()
ctxt.eval("function example(a = 'hello'){return a;}")
render = ctxt.eval("example();")
print render
```

I get 
SyntaxError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token = (  @ 1 : 19 )  -> function example(a = 'hello'){return a;}

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default arguments are a feature of ES6.
PyV8 doesn't support ES6 syntax. You need to use a [shim/polyfil](https://github.com/addyosmani/es6-equivalents-in-es5#default-parameters):

```
import PyV8

jsFunc = """
function test(msg, name) {
  (msg === undefined) && (msg = 'hello');
  (name === undefined) && (name = 'world');
  return msg + ' ' + name
}
"""


ctxt = PyV8.JSContext()
ctxt.enter()
ctxt.eval(jsFunc)
render1 = ctxt.eval("test();")
render2 = ctxt.eval("test('hi');")
print render1
print render2
```

Prints:

```
hello world
hi world
```